# Download Excel works in Postman but doesn't in Javascript

Tags: javascript, axios, postman

I'm trying to download an Excel file via AJAX (using Axios). I'm doing this way because I need to send a JWT token to access to it.

Now, I'm getting a file response with the content like this:

[image: Data received]

Which seems to be binary. In Postman I can set the token and click *Save and download* button and all works. Now, this is my code in JS:

```
requestWithFullResponse({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
}, this.props.token, false).then((response) => {
  const responseData = response.data

  // I've tried with different types and nothing works
  // var blob = new Blob([responseData], { type: `${response.headers['content-type']};charset=utf-8` });
  // var blob = new Blob([responseData], { type: 'application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8' });
  var blob = new Blob([responseData], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

  saveAs(blob, filename, true)
}).catch((error) => { console.log('Error downloading file -> ', error); });
```

That code downloads the file, but when I open It it Libre Office says that the file is corrupt. What I'm missing? Is there a way to see the code executed by Postman when downloads the file?

Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: Try setting the `responseType: 'stream'` or `responseType: 'blob'`. The default is `application/json`

Comment: Thank you so much!  `responseType: 'blob'` did the trick! If you want make an aswer to be selected as the accepted one and close this question!

Comment: Glad to hear. Okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set: `responseType: 'blob'`. The default is `application/json`.